# Equivalent of assertRegexMatches in python 2.4

Tags: python, unit-testing

Say I have a regex

```
REGEX = re.compile('.*foo{')
```

How would you write a unit test that matches a set of string with python 2.4 ?

I know in python 2.7 I can use assertRegexMatches, unfortunately this doesn't work in 2.4 :/

I use self.assertEqual for the rest of my tests.

Cheers,
M

Comment: Just to clarify - it's `assertRegexpMatches` in 2.7 (note the p), and in Python 3, simply `assertRegex`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you asked about a set of string rather than a single string

```
def createMatcher( self, regex ):
    def matchCheck( argument ):
        self.assertTrue( regex.match( argument ) )
    return matchCheck
```

Then in your function:

```
map( self.createMatcher( REGEX ), mySetOfStrings )
```

Answer (score 6):

```
self.assertTrue(REGEX.match(text))
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want an exact match you can do this:

```
assertTrue(REGEX.match(data))
```

If you do not care where it matches then:

```
assertTrue(REGEX.search(data))
```

Keep in mind the [difference](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#matching-vs-searching) between matching and searching. Also if you are so inclined you can subclass `TestCase` and add your own assertion to do the above.

Answer (score 1):

For testing on earlier Python versions, I prefer to use `unittest2`:
http://pypi.python.org/pypi/unittest2/

It's a backport of `unittest` maintained by Michael Foord, the same developer that maintains the stdlib version.